# Why this knockout mapping code is not working?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of json objects which i want to map to knockout viewmodel list using ko mapping plugin. The below is my code (just to explain my problem, no need to take this code seriously):

```
var itemsList = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'A' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'B' },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'C' }
];

var item = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}

var listOfItems = ko.observableArray();

var listOfItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(itemsList, {
    create: function(options) {
        return new item(options.data);
    }
});
```

Now my listOfItems are always empty, why ??

Comment: Your code looks ok. Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could really simplify this code and it is become working well.

```
var itemsList = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'A' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'B' }, { Id: 3, Name: 'C' }];
var viewModel = {
    listOfItems: ko.mapping.fromJS(itemsList)
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Now you have viewModel with observableArray `listOfItems`, and all items in this array have `Id` and `Name` properties.
You can test it with folowing code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: listOfItems">
    <li> 
        <span data-bind="text: Id"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```